# Weird Python error

Tags: python, django

This error: `cancel_agreement() missing 1 required positional argument: 'agreement_id'`

appeared while executing this method:

```
def force_cancel(self):
    api = model_from_ref(self.processor.api)
    api.cancel_agreement(self.subscription_reference)
    # transaction.cancel_subscription()  # runs in the callback
```

Here is `cancel_agreement()` method:

```
def cancel_agreement(self, agreement_id, is_upgrade=False):
    note = _("Upgrading billing plan") if is_upgrade else _("Canceling a service")
    r = self.session.post(self.server + '/v1/payments/billing-agreements/%s/cancel' % agreement_id,
                          data='{"note": "%s"}' % note,
                          headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
    if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        raise RuntimeError(_("Cannot cancel a billing agreement at PayPal. Please contact support."))
```

I don't understand why the error happens: It is calling a two-argument function (`api` and `self.subscription_reference`) and its definition is also two required arguments (`self` and `agreement_id`).

Sadly I can't show the entire code, because my business partner is against releasing it open source.

Comment: `cancel_aggrement` should be called by `self`. Not `api`. Right?

Comment: What is the relationship between `api` and the class that owns the method `force_cancel`? What is `type(api)`?

Comment: Is `api` instance of class in which `cancel_agreement` is present ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `type(api)` is `"PayPalAPI"`. There is no relation between the class `Transaction` which owns `force_cancel` and `PayPalAPI` (except that some methods call other's methods as in the code in the question)

Comment: Yes, `api` is an instance of class in which `cancel_agreement` is present

Comment: You may debug this by modifying `cancel_agreement` so that it accepts an arbitrary number of positional arguments: `def cancel_argreement(*args, is_upgrade=False):`. Then you can `print()` or log the list of arguments it receives. This will also tell you whether this implementation of the method gets called at all or whether it gets overwritten or overloaded somewhere. (Though, the stack trace of your current error message should also tell you whether that's the case.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only case this can happen is if `cancel_agreement` isn't a bound method in that context. Hence `type(api)` should yield `<class 'PayPalAPI'>` (new style classes) or `<type 'instance'>`.

Comment: @dhke yeah, the **exact** output of `type(api)` would help

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
def force_cancel(self):
    klass = model_from_ref(self.processor.api)
    api = klass()
    api.cancel_agreement(self.subscription_reference)
```